# Context type variable in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

I have implemented a FragmentPagerAdapter with 4 tabs and I have associated a fragment to each of them.
One of the views loads a GridView with images as follows:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.init, container, false);

    final GridView grid = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.myGrid);            
    grid.setNumColumns(2);
    grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    return view;
}
```

The problem is that the method 'new ImageAdapter(context)' receives as a parameter a variable type Context to load in method 'newImageView (context)' that it needs this type of variable and passing 'this' the variable is type Fragment but not Context, by what fails, how I can fix?

How do I pass a variable Context type within a class that inherits from Fragment?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `getActivity()` like `grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));`

Comment: Thanks, but now I have next mistake: "No enclosing instance of type IniSel is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type IniSel (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of IniSel)." (IniSel is the Class name)

Comment: @KryNaC how did you solve this issue?

Comment: @KryNaC, sorry, further search found that you need to change class ImageAdapter to static class ImageAdapter

Comment: @benkol yes, this is the reason.